# can't populate a table from a query that has an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I have succesfully been able to move an array of 72 values to new sheet:(whith much help from you all and a little luck on my part) verified by the `print_r`

howvever, I am getting "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in .../admin/emailall.php on line 14

The query is valid when I enter in a number

```
<?php
include "inc.php";
//print_r ($_POST);

$Pnum=implode(',',$_POST);
$querymail=mysql_query("select sp.email_address as email from stats_player sp
where sp.player_num IN $Pnum");
//have tried ($Pnum) '$Pnum' (".'$Pnum'.") and I think a few other cominations

echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($querymail))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row['email']."</td></tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

the table is tempory and and simpy a check

Comment: What is the value for $Pnum?  You should add mysql_error() handling so you can see specific error messages when attempting the query.

Comment: Please show the print_r output.

Comment: Bill $_POST is an array in the form $_POST['fieldname1'], $_POST['fieldname2']. Doing `implode(',',$_POST);` wont work it need a field name like `implode(',',$_POST['fieldname1']);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here is the printout (middle is cut out): `Array ( [Email_Submit] => Email [checkemail] => Array ( [0] => 554 [1] => 553 [2] => 11 [3] => 564 [4] => 100 [5] => 98 ......[70] => 88 [71] => 267 ) ) `

Comment: It seems to me you rather want all elements of `$_POST['checkemail'`] to appear in your query instead of all elements of `$_POST`. You should replace `$Pnum=implode(',',$_POST);` by `$Pnum=implode(',',$_POST['checkemail']);` if that's the case.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You got it...`$Pnum=implode(',',$_POST['checkemail']);` works like a charm! Someone care to officially answer? so I can check it?

Comment: @BillFlippen ok done a proper answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill

$_POST is an array in the form $_POST['fieldname1'], $_POST['fieldname2'].

Doing `implode(',',$_POST);` wont work it need a field name like `implode(',',$_POST['fieldname1']);`

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` keywords needs a list of the form `(firstVal, secondVal,...)`. So,

```
"SELECT sp.email_address AS email FROM stats_player sp
WHERE sp.player_num IN ($Pnum)"
```

should work assuming $Pnum contains numbers only (strings would have to be surrounded by `'`s)

Comment: I have tried that....currently active in code and is still failing `$querymail=mysql_query("select sp.email_address as email from stats_player sp where sp.player_num IN ($Pnum)");

echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($querymail))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row['email']."</td></tr>";`

Comment: What does `echo mysql_error();` show you if you place it right after `mysql_query()`?